# Is there a way to get the console to display the list with the highest value?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm making a tournament scoring system at the minute and I have made it so for every team, there is a list where all there points are scored. For example, the code looks a bit like this

```
Console.WriteLine("First Place: ");
Console.ReadLine();
if (Console.ReadLine() == Team1)
{ 
  team1.Add(5)
}

if (Console.ReadLine() == Team2)
{
  team2.Add(5)
}
```

And it goes on like that. Is there any way I could make the console display the team that got the highest amount of points? As I want to display the overall winner at the end.

Comment: Sure, what did you try so far? Can you sum up the scores? Compare the sums? Write the winner team to the Console? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Im just stuck on how to display the winner and i haven't really tried anything yet as i dont know where to start and which command i would need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've better to do something like this :
Create your Team Model :

```
public class Team
{
   publc int Points {get; set;}
}
```

Then Create your Teams :

```
Team team1 = new Team();
```

You have to create a List of teams : `List<Team> teams = new List<Team>();`

Then you can add your teams : `teams.Add(team1);`

Then add your points `team1.Points += 5;`

And at the end :

```
Team winner = teams.OrderBy(x => x.Points).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: No problem, can you mark my answer as correct ? :)

Comment: How could I read user input to name these Teams though because im trying to do the Team1 = console.ReadLine but its showing up with errors

Comment: You have to add a property in your Team Class, so in your class you will have public int Points {get; set;} public string Name {get; set;} and then you can use it like this : team1.Name = Console.ReadLine();

Comment: thanks man you've helped a lot